# NSObjectInaccessibleException CoreData could not fulfill a fault - still confused

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I see this issue has been asked a bit but all the answers seem to point to the cause being trying to update an object when the context has been deleted. I don't think I'm doing that but I'm getting the error so I'm confused (admittedly, I'm shaky on managing retention and references to begin with).

I have an Entity that holds user preferences as essentially key-value records. One of them is an email address.

```
UserPreference *prefEmailAddress;

@property (nonatomic, retain) UserPreference *prefEmailAddress;
```

In my class, in my ViewWillAppear method, I build a fetch request and get a reference to the email address value and set a UI text box to the value. This works fine.

```
NSArray *prefs = [context executeFetchRequest:request error: &error];

if ([prefs count] > 0) {
  prefEmailAddress = [prefs objectAtIndex:0];
  [prefEmailAddress setValue:emailAddress.text forKey:@"prefValue"];
}
```

However, in another method when I try to save the potentially modified text box text back to the object, I get the above crash.

I'm just doing this;

```
NSLog(@"Addr: %@",emailAddress.text);
//    [prefEmailAddress setValue:emailAddress.text forKey:@"prefValue"];
```

The last line causes the exception. Seems like the prefEmailAddress object should still exist but it apparently doesn't.

Thanks for any hints on this.

Answer (score 0):

I solved mine by removing

```
[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:<INT_VALUE>];
```

if this is in your code when fetching request.